# How to generate comments like Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, comments

How to generate comments like this(From Sails.js)：

```
  //    ██╗    ██╗███╗   ██╗██╗     ██╗███╗   ██╗███████╗  ██╗
  //   ██╔╝    ██║████╗  ██║██║     ██║████╗  ██║██╔════╝  ╚██╗
  //  ██╔╝     ██║██╔██╗ ██║██║     ██║██╔██╗ ██║█████╗     ╚██╗
  //  ╚██╗     ██║██║╚██╗██║██║     ██║██║╚██╗██║██╔══╝     ██╔╝
  //   ╚██╗    ██║██║ ╚████║███████╗██║██║ ╚████║███████╗  ██╔╝
  //    ╚═╝    ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝  ╚═╝
```

Is there a generator?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also find online ascii generators like this one: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Big%20Money-ne&t=Do%20you%20mean%20like%20this%3F%0A

Answer (score 1):

Install [KIT](https://github.com/mikermcneil/kit) and use the command `kit exclaim TEXT` replace `TEXT` with your own so it

```
//  ██╗      ██████╗  ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗███████╗    ██╗     ██╗██╗  ██╗███████╗    
//  ██║     ██╔═══██╗██╔═══██╗██║ ██╔╝██╔════╝    ██║     ██║██║ ██╔╝██╔════╝    
//  ██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║█████╔╝ ███████╗    ██║     ██║█████╔╝ █████╗      
//  ██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██╔═██╗ ╚════██║    ██║     ██║██╔═██╗ ██╔══╝      
//  ███████╗╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║  ██╗███████║    ███████╗██║██║  ██╗███████╗    
//  ╚══════╝ ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝    ╚══════╝╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝    
//                                                                               
//  ████████╗██╗  ██╗██╗███████╗                                                 
//  ╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║██║██╔════╝                                                 
//     ██║   ███████║██║███████╗                                                 
//     ██║   ██╔══██║██║╚════██║                                                 
//     ██║   ██║  ██║██║███████║                                                 
//     ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝╚══════╝                                                 
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Google [nodejs ascii art](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs%20ascii%20art), It will show several node packages pick one to your liking.